# Global variables vs properties for creating an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have create tableview in viewDidLoad() method, it works great, but if I want to access to my tableview in other method, I cann't do this. What is the best way for implementing UITableView. Variables with closure, properties?

```
let maintable:UITableView=UITableView()
    maintable.frame=CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350)
    maintable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false
    maintable.delegate=self
    maintable.datasource=self
    self.view.adsubview(maintable)
```

variables with closure. Here `maintable.delegate=self` throws an error

```
 let mytable:UITableView={

    let maintable:UITableView=UITableView()
    maintable.frame=CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350)
    maintable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false

    return maintable

}()
```

Comment: what error do you get when you set `maintable.delegate = self` ?

Comment: You should probably be assigning your `UITableView` to an instance variable, so that it is always accessible in your controller regardless of which method you're in, without having to pass it around.

Comment: Type 'mainCont->()->mainCony!' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate' but UITableViewDelegate and UITableDataSource implemented

Comment: `maintable.delegate=self` is getting a compile error because `=something` is a prefix operator. You always need a space in there: `maintable.delegate = self`. (And it's easier to read.)

Comment: Yes but maintable.delegate = self gives same error

Comment: Oh right, you need to declare that your class conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. I'll edit my answer below.

Comment: My class looks                                                                  class mainCont: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {}

Comment: I have found answer:«If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `mainTableView` as an instance variable. Its scope is currently limited to your `viewDidLoad` method, even though the table view itself persists (since you add it to your view before it disappears). You'll also want to make sure your class conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

```
class MyViewController : ViewController {
    var mainTable: UITableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        maintable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350)
        maintable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        maintable.delegate = self
        maintable.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(maintable)
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    // lots of optional methods
}

extension MyViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        // return the cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyViewController : ViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource
{
    let mainTable: UITableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        maintable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350)
        maintable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        maintable.delegate = self
        maintable.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(maintable)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (Any_Number_Of_Rows_You_Want_To_Have)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell = UITableViewCell dequeuereusablecellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.titlelabel.text = "Error Resolved"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how your code solves the problem?